# Send data to Algolia Search with Azure data factory

Tags: .net, azure-functions, azure-data-factory, algolia

I need to send all details from CosmosDB to Algolia Search through the Azure data factory.
Is there any way to do this except creating the Azure Function?
I have tried to use Copy activity but in sink, I am not able to get Algolia search Configuration.

Comment: I'm afraid no, Data Factory doesn't support Algolia Search as connector. We must achieve that in code level,  the ways are create function/databrick notebooks and executing it in Data Factory.

Comment: thanks..still Azure data factory is work in progress.

Comment: JHi @shashank shekhar, you're welcome, may I post it answer?

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, hope you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data Factory doesn't support Algolia Search as connector. We can get this from this document: [Azure Data Factory connector overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-overview).

It means that we can't send the data to Algolia Search directly with Data Factory actives. We need achieve that in code level, the ways are create function/databrick notebooks and executing it in Data Factory.  The next step is focus on how design the code and run it in Data Factory.

HTH.